# How to add XML element A to element B which doesn't have A as a child element

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I am processing a [gpx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_eXchange_Format) file which resembles xml. Here's an extract of that file:

```
<trkpt lat="3.1398377" lon="101.6937661">
    <ele>0.0</ele>
    <time>2013-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</time>
    <name>Position 1</name>
</trkpt>

<trkpt lat="3.1250538" lon="101.6783237">
    <ele>0.0</ele>
    <name>Position 460</name>
</trkpt>
```

As you can see, some of the `<trkpt>` elements contain the `<time>` element and some don't.
How do I add `<time>` to those `<trkpt>` elements that don't contain it?

While the file is being read, this produces error if the XML node doesn’t contain `<time>`:

```
foreach $points ( $root->getElementsByTagName('trkpt') ) {
    my($lat)  = $points->findvalue('@lat');
    my($lon)  = $pints->findvalue('@lon');
    my($time) = $points->getElementsByTagName('time')->[0]->textContent();
    my($pointName)  = $points->getElementsByTagName('name')->[0]->textContent();
}
```

> Can't call method "textContent" on an undefined value at ...

How can I make it more intelligent? That is, if it encounters undefined `$time`, it will write the `<time>` into the gpx file, and no error occurs.

Comment: Are there multiple `trkpt` elements in your file, or are you showing two files in your example?

Comment: yes, there are 2 many `trkpt` elements. What i want to do is, insert element `<time>` after `<ele>` for every nodes `<trkpt>` do not have. these elements are in the file `gps.gpx` (a hella lot of data!)

Comment: OK then how big is the file? `XML::Twig` may be a better option.

Comment: GPX doesn't resemble XML - it *is* XML!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the size of your file you may want to go with either [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML), which reads the entire XML document into memory, or [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig), which will allow you to process the XML as a stream and minimize the memory used.

For testing purposes 
I have added a root element `<root>` to your input data to make it well-formed XML, like this

```
<root>
  <trkpt lat="3.1398377" lon="101.6937661">
    <ele>0.0</ele>
    <time>2013-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</time>
    <name>Position 1</name>
  </trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="3.1250538" lon="101.6783237">
    <ele>0.0</ele>
    <name>Position 460</name>
  </trkpt>
</root>
```

This is a solution using `XML::LibXML`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'trkpt.xml');

for my $trkpt ($doc->findnodes('/*/trkpt')) {
  unless ($trkpt->exists('time')) {
    my ($ele) = $trkpt->findnodes('ele');
    my $time = $doc->createElement('time');
    $time->appendTextNode('0.0');
    $trkpt->insertAfter($time, $ele);
  }
}

print $doc->toString(1);
```

and here is an equivalent usiong `XML::Twig`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
  twig_roots => { trkpt => \&trkpt },
  twig_print_outside_roots => 1,
  pretty_print => 'indented'
);
$twig->parsefile('trkpt.xml');

sub trkpt {
  my ($twig, $trkpt) = @_;
  unless ($trkpt->has_child('time')) {
    my $time = XML::Twig::Elt->new(time => '0.0');
    my $ele = $trkpt->first_child('ele');
    $time->paste('after', $ele);
  }
  $twig->flush;
}
```

Comment: yes, I was almost there I didnt know "insertAfter" ever existed. LOL. thank you very much.  Really.

Answer (score 5):

- Use an XML parser. [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML) will do nicely here.
- Loop over all `<trkpt>` nodes:

  ```
  for my $node ( $xml->findnodes( '//trkpt') ) { ... }
  ```
- Use `exists` (or `findnodes` for older versions of `XML::LibXML`) to detect if the `<time>` node exists:

  ```
  if $node->exists( './time' ) { ... }
  ```

Comment: what if '<time'> node does not exist, how can I write '<time>' to the xml file?

Comment: how to immediately write "<time>" node after the "<ele> node?